# Stack Overflow has left!

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, ios-app

Stack Overflow seems to have abandoned us iOS users! Look:

[image: stack Overflow is missing!]

What has happened?!

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 5s (Global)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)

Comment: I hear Stack Apps is cool. You should switch to that instead. They have userscripts.

Comment: Where are you accessing that screen from? I'm unable to reproduce this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out.

The "All Sites" page on the iOS app removes any sites that you have pinned to your sidebar. As you can see, Stack Overflow is pinned to my sidebar:

[image: sidebar]

I only noticed this when I realised that none of my sites that were pinned showed up in the list of sites. So this isn't really a bug!

Comment: So it's not really "pinned", it's more like you can control the order in which they appear... :)